# Как показать знак вопроса, если вопросительное предложение цитируется не полностью?

Tags: цитата, вопрос, многоточие

Аят Корана: Они [ангелы] сказали: "Неужели Ты поселишь там того, кто будет распространять нечестие и проливать кровь, тогда как мы прославляем Тебя хвалой и освящаем Тебя?"
В тексте требуется указать только начало цитаты:
Они сказали: "Неужели Ты поселишь там того, кто будет распространять нечестие...?"
Как правильно оформить отсутствие конца цитаты и наличие вопросительного знака?
Я понимаю, что "...?" не годится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если цитата приводится не полностью, то пропуск обозначается многоточием, которое ставится после цитаты (перед закрывающими кавычками), когда цитируемое предложение приводится не до конца:

*Выступая в защиту культуры устной речи, Чехов писал: «В сущности ведь для интеллигентного человека дурно говорить должно бы считаться таким же неприличием, как не уметь читать и писать…»*

Ваш случай "не попадает" под это правило, потому что в самом конце цитаты стоит вопросительный знак. Если поставить знак **«?..»**, то будет непонятно, вся ли цитата приведена в тексте.

Вот что рекомендует [Издательский словарь-справочник](https://publishing_dictionary.academic.ru/509/%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8):
**УГЛОВЫЕ СКОБКИ**, или **ломаные скобки**, — парный знак, в который заключают многоточие, показывающее в цитате купюру, составляющую **либо целое предложение или фразу**, либо несколько предложений (фраз).

Я думаю, что вы можете написать так:
**Они [ангелы] сказали: «Неужели Ты поселишь там того, кто будет распространять нечестие <...>?»**

Про особенности цитирования можно прочитать здесь:
[Техника цитирования и редакционное оформление цитат](http://genling.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000026/st055.shtml)

**Дополнение** (по рекомендации @М_Г):

Я ориентировалась на пример из [справочника Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=454):
§ 144. При сокращении цитаты, уже имеющей многоточия, выполняющие те или иные свойственные им функции, многоточие, поставленное автором, цитирующим текст, указывающее на сокращение цитаты, заключается в угловые скобки:
*В дневнике Л. Н. Толстого читаем: «Она не может отречься от своего чувства ‹...›. У нее, как у всех женщин, первенствует чувство, и всякое изменение происходит, может быть, независимо от разума, в чувстве... Может быть, Таня права, что это само собой понемногу пройдет **‹...›».***

По правилам точка цитаты выносится за кавычки, а вопросительный и восклицательные знаки остаются внутри них. Получается, что мы сокращаем только текст, а знак окончания предложения оставляем за угловой скобкой (перед кавычками).

Comment: Может быть тогда так. Они сказали: "Неужели Ты поселишь там того, кто будет распространять нечестие... <...>?" Первое многоточие вместо слов "и проливать кровь,", а угловые скобки вместо придаточного предложения "тогда как мы прославляем Тебя хвалой и освящаем Тебя".

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы перемудрили. Не, так не пойдёт. Посмотрите ещё вот здесь: https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091470.html (8.5.4) **_Предложение цитаты с опущенными в конце словами (последним словом)… <…> …Предложение цитаты с опущенными начальными словами (первым словом)._**

Comment: По-моему всё так и есть, только отсутствует третья часть "…Предложение цитаты с опущенными начальными словами (первым словом)."

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно. _Такое многоточие [в угловых скобках], заменяющее текст из **одного или нескольких предложений,** опущенных при цитировании  сочетается... с многоточием, если в конце **предшествующего** предложения цитаты или начале **последующего** предложения опущены слова._ Т. е. указанная в правиле конструкция "подходит" (как минимум) для **трёх** предложений, а у Вас только **одно.**

Comment: Римма Михайлова,  Ваше предложение — результат творческой переработки указанных источников (в них наш случай не описан), не так ли?

Comment: По-моему в (8.5.4) даётся ОБЩИЙ вариант, из которого мы можем выделить РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ части (что я и сделал). А предложением можно рассматривать придаточное предложение, или его можно рассматривать как фразу (Ваша цитата из Издательского словаря-справочника "либо целое предложение или фразу").

Comment: @М_Г Я ориентировалась на пример из справочника Лопатина (http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=454). _В дневнике Л. Н. Толстого читаем: «Она не может отречься от своего чувства ‹...›. У нее, как у всех женщин, первенствует чувство, и всякое изменение происходит, может быть, независимо от разума, в чувстве... Может быть, Таня права, что это само собой понемногу пройдет **‹...›»._** По правилам точка цитаты выносится за кавычки, а вопросительный и восклицательные знаки остаются внутри них. Получается, что мы сокращаем только текст, а знак окончания предложения оставляем за угловой скобкой.

Comment: @М_Г «Господа, неужели об этой стремительной мощи, об этой гениальной силе наших предков помнят только кадеты морского корпуса, которые поставили на месте Гангутской битвы скромный крест из сердобольского гранита?» (П. А. Столыпин) Неоконченную цитату с вопр. знаком в конце я бы оформила так. Столыпин возмущался: «Господа, неужели об этой стремительной мощи, об этой гениальной силе наших предков помнят только кадеты морского корпуса ‹...›?» Разве неправильно?

Comment: А если опустить слова "морского корпуса" и поставить вместо них просто многоточие, то получится "мой" вариант.  Столыпин возмущался: «Господа, неужели об этой стремительной мощи, об этой гениальной силе наших предков помнят только кадеты... ‹...›?» Разве неправильно?

Comment: Римма Михайлова, Ссылка на Лопатина убеждает. Спасибо! Советую добавить ее в ответ.

Comment: @Рад Дважды многоточие — перебор.

Comment: Но ведь у меня пропущена не только фраза (законченный смысл), что выражается угловыми скобками, но и перед этим слова. Как тогда это отобразить? У Лопатина такой вариант не рассматривается, но ведь это не означает, что его не может быть.

Comment: К дополнению в ответе. В изначальной цитате НЕТ "своего" многоточия, все сокращения сделаны автором не цитаты, а цитирующим. То есть, по-моему, это правило не подходит.

Comment: Рад, есть два варианта: 1. Просто поставить многоточие (тогда не будет вопр. знака). 2. Использовать в конце цитаты угловые скобки с вопр. знаком после них. Пример из Лопатина приведен для того, чтобы было понятно: в самом конце предложения **могут** находиться угловые скобки.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, непосредственно после многоточия может стоять только **слово**.
Остается надеяться, что читатель поймет, что цитируется вопросительное предложение. Или ухитритесь включить в цитату последнее слово предложения, например так: "Неужели Ты поселишь там того, кто будет распространять нечестие... тогда как мы прославляем... Тебя?"

Comment: По контексту нужна часть цитаты без окончания.